# Ограничение в сессии

Tags: ubuntu

Как убрать ограничение в сессии на последней ubuntu?
Т.е у меня автоматически начинает блокироваться сессия и приходится заново заходить при этом заново включать программы, которые выключились

Comment: Ограничение на что? Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы.

Comment: @AK, можно предположить, что вместо разблокировки x-сессии вопрошающий создаёт новую. а вот **почему** он так делает — пока неизвестно.